# ArcGIS Selecting Everything within the circles on map

Tags: python, arcgis, arcgis-server, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-online

I am new to ArcGIS. I have been tasked with making a python script that will select the regions within the larger circles below.

[image]

So in other words make a selection of everything in the larger green, red, and light blue circles above.  I am not sure if this is even possible so could someone let me know if it is possible and direct me to whatever documentation or other resources I need to review on it to make this happen?

At the moment we are using Arcgis Online but may need to use ArcGIS Pro to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

This is totally doable with agol/Arcgis Enterprise GeometryServer, or arcgis api for python.
// First aproach
1 - First you merge the biggest geometry.

2- Then, you will subtract the smallest geometry. Now you have the geometry to make the selection.

3- select every FeatureLayer you want with the resultant geometry from steps 1,2

//Second aproach

1 - Make one spatial join with biggest buffer

2 - Make another spatial join with smallest buffer

3 - The result objectids should be only in the biggest buffer, use it to do the selection.

```py
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.features import GeoAccessor
import os
gis = GIS("home")

gdb_path = os.path.abspath('./arcgis-selecting-everything-within-the-circles-on-map.gdb')
# Get the feature layer
## you can also use the feature layer url
## big_buff = GeoAccessor.from_featureclass('https://url/FeatureServer/0')
big_buff = GeoAccessor.from_featureclass(os.path.join(gdb_path, 'mypoints_Buffer2'))
small_buff = GeoAccessor.from_featureclass(os.path.join(gdb_path, 'mypoints_Buffer'))

points = GeoAccessor.from_featureclass(os.path.join(gdb_path, 'mypoints'))


big_buff_merged = big_buff.dissolve()

p1 = points.spatial.join(big_buff, op='within').drop_duplicates(subset=['OBJECTID_left'])[['OBJECTID_left']]
p2 = points.spatial.join(small_buff, op='within').drop_duplicates(subset=['OBJECTID_left'])[['OBJECTID_left']]

result = p1.merge(p2, how='outer', indicator=True).query('_merge == "left_only"').drop(columns=['_merge'])
result = points.merge(result, how='inner', left_on='OBJECTID', right_on='OBJECTID_left').drop(columns=['OBJECTID_left'])
result
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: for online layers you can use:
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayer \n
fl = FeatureLayer(url) \n
sdf = fl.query().sdf